# how can i change specific datagridview cell value?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the data from database, but one attribute on database record is bit (boolean).
For example

```
name, surname, date, itHave
A      B     2020    1//
C      D     2021    0
```

The form application side, data is ok. I can see the records. But i want to change 1 and 0 as Yes or No.

I tried
number(the count of datagridview)

```
for( i=0; i< number; i++){

   if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() =="1"){
       MessageBox.Show("Test");
       dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = "Yes";
   }

}
```

MessageBox.Show("Test"); // this is running
but it does not happen.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example look fine and works. I've created initial `DataGridView` with some `0-1` values at "It Have" column:

[image]

Then used your example (edited just a bit by adding a ternary):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3];
    cell.Value = cell.Value.ToString() == "1" ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

And get `Yes/No` instead of `1-0` as well:

[image]

Note, that your `MessageBox.Show("Test");` would block code execution until you close it.

Comment: thank u but it is running for other cells A B Date ok but itHave is bit on the database SQL. now System.Exception: Yes int32 and System.FormatException error

Comment: If you mean type mismatch when communicating with database, so probably in your database column "It Have" has integer type, but you set values "Yes/No" which is of string type (or varchar).

Answer (score 0):

Make your db data in human readable text, you can use anonymous types in LINQ:

```
var items = mydbitems.Select(x => new 
                                  {
                                     Name = x.name,
                                     Surname = x.surname,
                                     Date = x.date,
                                     itHave = x.itHave == 1 ? "yes" : "no"
                                  };
datagridview.DataSource = items.ToList();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).